# Some threads in Java ForkJoinPool become idle once in a while

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

I've a Java code like below:

```
Stream<String> stream = getStreamFromSomewhere()
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(32);
pool.submit(() -> stream.parallel()
                        .filter(condition)
                        .forEach(x -> recursive(x))).get();
pool.shutdown();
```

Now this code runs quick enough, using all 32 threads in my machine, each utilized at around 70-80%.

Oddly, after every few mins or so, the CPU util of all threads go down to 0% except 2 threads (or sometimes 1) which goes up to 100%. A minute or so later, it would be alright with all of them humming along at 70-80% again. This behavior repeats every few mins or so.

I'm unable to pinpoint what could cause this. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: How many cores , what os, how are you monitoring?? What's the nature of task given to pool, CPU bound or I/O bound? Is the task paralleized properly?
In addition to monitoring just the CPU usage, you should also be looking at swapping , voluntary and involuntary context-switch, On ubuntu, mpstat would give you insights.

Comment: Can you submit the whole code? I'd like to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Different Java threads aren't necessarily required to run on different CPU threads. Your 32 Java threads could, theoretically, equally share 1/32nd of the time on a single CPU thread. That would be somewhat wasteful if the other 31 CPU threads were unused but it's still possible.

Exactly how the tasks are divided up onto CPU threads is down to the [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)). In your case, the scheduler is deciding, for whatever reason, that it needs split the 32 Java threads across 2 CPU threads.

I don't even know how you would begin debugging something like that. It's out of your control and (practically) always will be, so why worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

Something else running on your machine is determined to have a higher priority than your program so the CPU may switch to that instead of your pooled tasks.